# Owl carousel was working...then somehow I broke it after i re-added a missing <?php wp_footer(); ?>?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, owl-carousel

This owl carousel was working perfectly until... I added `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` in my footer. I had deleted by mistake and saw that it was missing, and now my owl carousel is broken! What did I do? I'm not sure why it is messing it up. I have to have that `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` or it is going to cause other things to break.

I'm going to post a link to the website. [Please view div site here](http://www.cloudpointtech.com/x123/)

I'll post the code for the footer but if you need any code for anything else that you can't get by going to the website let me know.

```html
<!-- BEGIN FULL FOOTER SECTION--> 
<footer>
<!--BEGIN TOP FOOTER SECTION--> 
        <div id="footer_top" class="clearfix">
            <div id="footer_top_content" class="clearfix">
                <div id="social_container" class="clearfix">
                    <a id="twitter" href="https://facebook.com/cloudpointtech" target="_blank">
                    <span class="footer_fontawesome_social"></span><br />
                    </a>
                    <a id="twitter1" href="https://twitter.com/cloudpointtech" target="_blank">
                    <span class="footer_fontawesome_social"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a id="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/cloud-point-technology" target="_blank">
                    <span id="footer_textspan22"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a id="email" href="mailto:support@cloudpointtech.com">
                    
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="footer_links_Container" class="clearfix">
                    <div id="left_links" class="clearfix">
                        <p id="footer_text10">
                        <span class="footer_fontawesome">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a class="footer_menu_link" href="http://www.cloudpointtech.com/managed-services/">Managed Services</a><br />
                        </p>
                        <p id="footer_text11">
                        <span class="footer_fontawesome">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a class="footer_menu_link" href="http://www.cloudpointtech.com/managed-medical-it/">Medical Managed Services</a><br />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right_links" class="clearfix">
                        <p id="footer_text12">
                        <span class="footer_fontawesome">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a class="footer_menu_link" href="http://www.cloudpointtech.com/support/">Support</a><br />
                        </p>
                        <p id="footer_text13">
                        <span class="footer_fontawesome">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a class="footer_menu_link" href="http://www.cloudpointtech.com/contact/">Contact</a><br />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="social_container1" class="clearfix">
                    <p class="icon_holder">
                        <a class="icon_holder_item" href="https://facebook.com/cloudpointtech" target="_blank">
                            <span class="footer_fontawesome_social"></span></a>
                    </p>
                    <p class="icon_holder">
                        <a class="icon_holder_item" href="https://twitter.com/cloudpointtech" target="_blank">
                            <span class="footer_fontawesome_social"></span></a>
                    </p>
                    <p class="icon_holder">
                        <a class="icon_holder_item" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/cloud-point-technology" target="_blank">
                            <span class="footer_fontawesome_social"></span></a>
                    </p>
                    <p class="icon_holder">
                                            <a class="icon_holder_item" href="mailto:support@cloudpointtech.com">

                                                <span class="footer_fontawesome_social"></span></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END OF TOP FOOTER CONTAINER-->     
    <!-- BEGIN BOTTOM FOOTER CONTAINER--> 
        <div id="footer_bottom" class="clearfix">
            <div id="footer_bottom_content" class="clearfix">
                <div class="footer_wrapper">
                    <span class="footer_text_link">Copywrite &copy; 2013 CloudPoint Technology</span><br />
                </div>
                <div class="footer_wrapper">  
                   <span class="footer_text_link">Created and Developed By 
                      <a href="http://www.cyndeeadkinsdesign.com" target="_blank">Cyndee Adkins Design</a></span><br />
                </div>
                <div class="footer_wrapper">
                <a class="footer_text_link" href="http://www.cloudpointtech.com/site-map/">Site Map</a>
            <span class="footer_text_link"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &middot; &nbsp; &nbsp; </span>
        <a class="footer_text_link" href="http://www.cloudpointtech.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
                        <span class="footer_text_link"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &middot; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</span>
                           <a class="footer_text_link" href="http://www.cloudpointtech.com/wp-login.php">Login</a><br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script>new WOW().init();</script>
 <script>var __adobewebfontsappname__ = "reflow"</script>
 <script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/open-sans:n7,i7,n8,i8,i4,n3,i3,n4,n6,i6:all.js"></script>
    
<!-- END OF BOTTOM FOOTER CONTAINER--> 
</footer>
<!-- END FULL FOOTER SECTION --> 
</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking your browser console? It might help.

Comment: I've been checking that off and on. I fixed a few things but can't figure out why it still isnt working.. I honestly don't understand js well enough to know what it is saying to me. I know things have to be in order and I thought I had that well taken care of but maybe not?

Comment: You're enqueuing jQuery in the footer, but you have code that depends on it within the body. You'll need to move jQuery to the head, or enqueue your other code after jQuery.

Comment: How can I tell which one I need to move to the head?

Comment: I've just finished fixing a very similar problem on a site. Plugins unfortunately have a habit of 'colliding' with each other. In my case the problem was with a call to the_excerpt, which was customised by another plugin breaking the site. Not an easy fix, but you just might have to edit or drop any offending plugin. Disable all plugins, enable them one by one, find the offending one then enable it's code line by line (or section to section) to find the problem.

Comment: I went through Gavin and diactivated and reactivated the codes. Did not fix the issue but I went to http://validator.w3.org/ and I found it saying that "Line 396, Column 107: Element link is missing required attribute property." Does that mean it cannot find a specific stylesheet?

Comment: I figured it out! I was linking the wrong JS file. FIXED!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my functions file and now it works.

I was linking this incorrectly and added this instead.

```
 wp_register_script('jquery', "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js", false, null);
```

```html
// ******************* Include jQuery Properly ****************** //


function my_init() {
   
    
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  
    //load a JS file from by theme: js/theme.js
    wp_enqueue_script( 'midwayjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr.custom.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'midwayjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'midwayjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesloaded.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'midwayjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skrollr.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
}
        
}
add_action('init','my_init');
?>
```